# How do I set auto height on my CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've been searching for days these answers and some how I found it but I don't know how to configure properly to my project.
I followed this awesome video [iOS Dev 11: CollectionViews | Swift 5, XCode 11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aU_kTzMZHQ8&lc=UgxL_Doj0ZSNsV5aBR14AaABAg.9MnzHFKbYjl9MtA4L2Rqha)

This video works perfectly to me, but when we reach `sizeForItemAt` method he declares a static value. For my project, width could be static and I was able to fix according the result I want, but I am still facing difficult to adapt the height. I want it to be equal the text size of my label text, I want I result like this: [final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWGHO.jpg)

So, I know that I need to to this on `sizeForItemAt` method but I don't know how, here is how my code looks like:

**FactsCollectionViewCell:**

```
class FactsCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var lbFactsText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbCategories: UILabel!
    
    func setup(with facts: FactsData?, index: Int) {
        
        let result = facts!.result[index]
        
        lbFactsText.text = result.value
        print(result.value)
        if let category = result.categories.first {
            
            lbCategories.text = category!.uppercased()
            lbCategories.sizeToFit()
        } else {
            
            lbCategories.text = "UNCATEGORIZED"
            lbCategories.sizeToFit()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func btShare(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // still working on this button
    }
    
}
```

And this is my **MainViewController**:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var facts: FactsData?
    var factsManager = FactsManager()
    var numberOfCV = 0
    var resultValue: String = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var cvFacts: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sbSearchFacts: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var nbMainScreen: UINavigationBar!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        cvFacts.dataSource = self
        cvFacts.delegate = self
        cvFacts.collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        sbSearchFacts.isHidden = true
    }
    
    @IBAction func search(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        
        sbSearchFacts.resignFirstResponder()
        sbSearchFacts.isHidden = !sbSearchFacts.isHidden
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if segue.identifier == "segueMainToFact" {
            
            let vc = segue.destination as! FactViewController
            vc.receivedValue = resultValue
            
        }
    }
    
}

extension MainViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return numberOfCV
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = cvFacts.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FactsCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FactsCollectionViewCell
    
        cell.setup(with: facts, index: indexPath.row)
        return cell
    }
    
}

// SearchBar delegate extension for when tap to search button
extension MainViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        
        sbSearchFacts.isHidden = true
        sbSearchFacts.resignFirstResponder()
        
        if let realFact = sbSearchFacts.text {
            
            factsManager.factsRequest(realFact) { (facts) in
                
                self.facts = facts
                self.numberOfCV = self.facts!.total
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.cvFacts.reloadData()
                }
            } onError: { (error) in
                
                print(error)
            }

        }
    }
}

// Extension to configure cell sizes
extension MainViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        let width = view.frame.size.width
        return CGSize(width: width - 40, height: //HERE I NEED TO CALCULATE THE HEIGHT BUT I DONT KNOW HOW)
    }
}

// Extension for when you tap the cell
extension MainViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let index = indexPath.row
        let result = facts?.result[index]
        resultValue = result!.value
    }
}
```

Does anyone has a tip to fix it?

Comment: I would recommend switching to compositional layout, where automatically self-sizing cells based on content actually _work_. If you don't want to do that you will just have to call `systemLayoutSizeFitting` on a dummy model cell to find out what the height needs to be.

Comment: @matt I will search for that, thanks. Do I need to change any constraint to adapt it? I am currently using like this: https://imgur.com/a/ThQcTRl

Comment: I almost there: 

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        let width = view.frame.size.width
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FactsCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
        let height = cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(collectionView.contentSize)
        return CGSize(width: width - 40, height: height.height)
    }`

https://imgur.com/a/wqTbQY5

Comment: I commonly use `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting` instead https://www.google.com/search?q=uicollectionviewcell+preferredLayoutAttributesFitting&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&biw=1920&bih=975&sxsrf=ALeKk01Sv2NyT7ws2AEus0WoiasBsYIR-g%3A1620080747508&ei=a3iQYPvSHvbXz7sP8Jaa-Ag&oq=uicollectionviewcell+preferredLayoutAttributesFitting&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBwgjELECECcyBAgAEAoyBAgAEB46BwgAEEcQsAM6BggAEAcQHjoGCAAQDRAKUJkLWOkOYJUQaAFwAngAgAGWAYgBtwWSAQMwLjWYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwi7tNmLx67wAhX263MBHXCLBo8Q4dUDCA0&uact=5

Comment: Basically, it does not matter which method I choose, I need to use `collectioView.contentSize` as parameter right?

Comment: Like this, is not 100% working for me:

`let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FactsCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)`
`let height = cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(collectionView.contentSize)`

Comment: @matt , tried this one today but did not worked too. It broke my `CollectionViewCell` methods: https://medium.com/swift2go/implementing-a-dynamic-height-uicollectionviewcell-in-swift-5-bdd912acd5c8